# Start motion scene programmatically

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have a motion layout with this layoutDescription: `app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene"`

**scene.xml**

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/view_home_card_start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/view_home_card_end"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="left"
            motion:dragDirection="dragLeft" />
    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

I think that the xml of `view_home_card_start` and `view_home_card_end` is irrelevant.

How can  I call this animation programatically?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Finally Im doing  this:

```
((MotionLayout)findViewById(R.id.motionLayout)).transitionToEnd();
((MotionLayout)findViewById(R.id.motionLayout)).transitionToStart();
```

Comment: how does one add constraint attributes to the transition??

Comment: and could you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002303/motion-layout-reset-on-navigating-between-activities

Comment: How can I achieve reverse animation in MotionScene?

Comment: what if the motionLayout have many transitions how to choose one  ?

Comment: @merwanezio
Java: `((MotionLayout)findViewById(R.id.motionLayout)).transitionToState(R.id.end);`

Kotlin `binding.motionLayout.transitionToState(R.id.end)`

Where `R.id.end` is our constraintSetId. That's why that id cannot be duplicated.

Answer (score 20):

You can also do this in your xml with

```
motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
```

and

```
motion:autoTransition="animateToStart"
```

Comment: this is the right answer. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Do this in your Transition xml tag in your MotionScene, something like  

`<Transition
     app:autoTransition="animateToEnd" />`    

NB: you can use `app` instead of `motion` or vice versa

Answer (score 8):

If anyone's doing this from a fragment:

1. Import:

   ```
   import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout;
   ```
2. Instantiate MotionLayout:

   ```
   MotionLayout motionLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.your_motion_layout);
   ```
3. Transition to the end/start of motion:

   ```
   motionLayout.transitionToStart();
   ```

or

```
    motionLayout.transitionToEnd();
```

Comment: you may get a null pointer exception in a fragment. I suggest to use a view model fro that. declare a view state object (a sealed class) in view model and observe it from activity so you can call transitionToStart() and transitionToEnd() there safe. and instead of getting motion layout from findViewById in fragment which is dangerous for getting null pointer exeption you can change view state value of view model from fragment instead

Answer (score 8):

We can simply do like this
**motion_layout.transitionToEnd()**

But on Activity resumed, It'll start our animation so fast that we may miss the few or the whole animation. so I would suggest to add some delay like.

```
GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
        delay(1000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            motion_layout.transitionToEnd()
        }
    }
```

Also you'll need to add Coroutines dependency if not added.

> implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'

Answer (score 2):

```
In Latest Update of Constraint **2.0.0-beta1** Layout There are Public methods add in motion layout 
        you can get these methods with the help of motionlayout id 
    **motionLayout** 

     1. public void setProgress (float pos) 
     2. public void setTransition (int
           beginId,int endId)  
     3. public void setTransitionDuration (int
               milliseconds)  public void setTransitionListener
               (MotionLayout.TransitionListener listener)

     4. public void setState (int
               id,int screenWidth, 
                             int screenHeight)

     5. if(wantShowUi)
            {
                newUserActivityBinding.coordinatorLayout.transitionToStart();
            }
            else
            {
                newUserActivityBinding.coordinatorLayout.transitionToEnd();
            }

      <android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene_01"
                tools:showPaths="true">

            <View
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="361dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp"/>


        </android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has more than 2 states (start and end), then you can programatically call the `transitionToState()` method wich recieves the state's id

Example:

```
binding.yourMotionLayoutId.transitionToState(R.id.yourStatusId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making use of ***transitionToState()*** method to transition between states on some action.

```
fun navigateToPayment() {
    binding?.motionLayoutContainer?.transitionToState(R.id.statePayment)
}

fun navigateToShipping() {
    binding?.motionLayoutContainer?.transitionToState(R.id.stateShipping)
}
```

Also using the same method to handle back press in Activity.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    binding?.motionLayoutContainer?.currentState?.let{
        when(it) {
            R.id.paymentState -> {
                //go back to shipping
                binding?.layoutSheet?.transitionToState(R.id.shippingState)
            }
            R.id.shippingState -> {
                //go back to cart
                binding?.layoutSheet?.transitionToState(R.id.cartState)
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Transition State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    } ?: run{
        //finish activity
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use kotlin and binding system you don't even need create motion object just write so: **binding.root.transitionToEnd()**