# MotionLayout jump to end ConstraintSet programmatically

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

There is an option to jump to end `ConstraintSet` in XML in `MotionLayout`.

```
<Transition
    app:autoTransition="jumpToEnd"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/constraintStart"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/constraintEnd"
    motion:duration="300" />
```

Can this be done programmatically?

Comment: helpful link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437946/start-motion-scene-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to jump to a `ConstraintSet` set the progress of `MotionLayout` to 1.

```
motionLayout?.setProgress(1.0f)
```

When you have multiple transitions, then set the state of `MotionLayout` to final `ConstraintSet` and then set the progress to 1.

```
motionLayout?.setState(R.id.endConstraintSet,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT)
motionLayout?.setProgress(1.0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `transitionToEnd()` method of `MotionLayout`

Comment: transitionToEnd() is different from jumpToEnd()

Answer (score 0):

Use the setProgress to 1f method did take effect ,but I can not receive the onTransitionCompleted event in TransitionListener

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31034925)