# Collapsing Toolbar on Motion Layout with enterAlways behaviour

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I created Collapsing Toolbar based on the MotionLayout using this [example](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/xml/scene_10_header.xml)

It works good but in CoordinatorLayout it is possible to set `enterAlways` flag to achieve effect when Toolbar appears even on scroll up from the middle of the list. In MotionLayout I have to scroll the list to start to show up Toolbar. Is it possible to improve this behaviour?

Comment: you can start the motion_scene programmatically or from xml check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437946/start-motion-scene-programmatically